# Mysql replication server both master slave

Tags: mysql-replication

I have a mysql db in my box. Can I replicate it to another db on the same box?

ie, the same box would be both master and slave(s).

Are there other ways of achieving this? (I'm thinking pointers/references, because it's in the same db system)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can. Just run each instance on a different port.

Comment: Thanks, I just installed mysql again using a different port. Works - no troubles so far...

Answer (score 1):

Just need different data dirs/sockets, etc. so different my.cnf's.