# Mysql replication, one database server process

Tags: mysql, replication

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Mysql replication server both master slave](https://serverfault.com/questions/103669/mysql-replication-server-both-master-slave)

On my development box, I want to experiment with a replication setup. But I don't want to create several mysqld processes (is it even possible?).

I figured I have the main database in the process - have this as the master, then in the same process create the slave databases, and have the master data replicated into the databases that exist in the same db server. Is this possible? Is there an easier way of achieving this without trying to set up replication?

Maybe to put it more simply: I want my Mysql server to be both master and slave(s) at the same time.

Comment: Added question here: http://serverfault.com/questions/103669/mysql-replication-server-both-master-slave

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible. Every time you launch mysql it has to read my.cnf to get the port information, socket, data files, etc.   Change the port as well as the socket values.  You can use the same binary with just different config files.

I had to do a setup like this one time to overcome a 2GB limitation when the client could not upgrade to a 64 bit processor. They have multiple databases, so we created them on different ports and they act individually.